# How to perform a 3 table join with sparse lookup table

Tags: mysql, join

I have 3 tables companies, products, and companies_products.

```
companies (id, name)
products (id, name)
companies_products(company_id, product_id)
```

`companies_products` is sparse, in that **the only entries in it are for products that a company has subscribed to** - there is no entry for non-subscribed products). I am doing this to prevent having to update every company in the event that a new product is to be added.

Unfortunately **this makes getting list of what a company is and isn't subscribed to rather difficult** for me to figure out

Is there a way to query for a result from this data:

`company`

```
(id: 1, name: "Test Company")
```

`products`

```
(id: 1, name: "Product 1")
(id: 2, name: "Product 2")
(id: 3, name: "Product 3")
```

`company_products`

```
(company_id: 1, product_id: 1)
(company_id: 1, product_id: 2)
```

to get a result such as this?

```
(company_id: 1, product_id: 1, status: "enabled")
(company_id: 1, product_id: 2, status: "enabled")
(company_id: 1, product_id: 3, status: "disabled")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First part returns the Cartesian product of companies and products.

```
from       companies c
cross join products p
```

Then for every combination of Company - Product it checks if exists a record in the `companies_products` table.

> ```
> select     c.id, 
>            c.name, 
>            p.id, 
>            p.name,
>            if(cp.company_id is null, 'status: enabled', 'status: disabled') as status
> from       companies c
> cross join products p
> left join  companies_products cp
> on         cp.company_id = c.id
> and        cp.product_id = p.id
> ;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | name         | id | name      | status          
> -: | :----------- | -: | :-------- | :---------------
>  1 | Test Company |  1 | Product 1 | status: disabled
>  1 | Test Company |  2 | Product 2 | status: disabled
>  1 | Test Company |  3 | Product 3 | status: enabled
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=646abef5f7d883c275c0ea09ccd7ad45)*

Or you can use `EXISTS` to check if there is a record that match both identifiers.

> ```
> select     c.id, 
>            c.name, 
>            p.id, 
>            p.name,
>            if (exists (select 1
>                        from   companies_products cp
>                        where  cp.company_id = c.id
>                        and    cp.product_id = p.id) 
>                       ,'status: enabled', 'status: disabled') as status
> from       companies c
> cross join products p
> ;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | name         | id | name      | status          
> -: | :----------- | -: | :-------- | :---------------
>  1 | Test Company |  1 | Product 1 | status: enabled 
>  1 | Test Company |  2 | Product 2 | status: enabled 
>  1 | Test Company |  3 | Product 3 | status: disabled
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=7df4c3795ce2f16219a6ea60384fbc8b)*